Trouble with vite-plugin-markdown: Config Loading Error
To create an md file and use it in the parent component, I installed the package as shown below.
npm install vite-plugin-markdown --save-dev

I also checked the package.json file and it was installed properly as shown below.
"vite-plugin-markdown": "^2.2.0",

vite.config.ts
import markdownPlugin from 'vite-plugin-markdown';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [vue(), markdownPlugin()],
})

Why does the error below occur?

failed to load config from /home/ecoplanet/dev/yerin/wmuWallet/WmuWalletFronted/vite.config.ts
3:06:17 PM [vite] markdownPlugin is not a function
3:06:17 PM [vite] server restart failed

I hope that it will be displayed well by importing it as shown below in the parent component.
import terms1 from '@/assets/terms/terms1.md';

<template v-if="termsType === 1">
  <textarea class="terms" cols="60" rows="40">{{ terms1 }}</textarea>
</template>


Setup
The documentation suggests that all modes are imported by default, but in reality, you need to list the ones you require. For Vue, it could be the three I've mentioned, but you can check the rest in the documentation.
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import { plugin as markdownPlugin, Mode } from "vite-plugin-markdown";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    markdownPlugin({
      mode: [Mode.MARKDOWN, Mode.HTML, Mode.VUE], // here need define modes
    }),
  ],
});


Without modes
With modes

Get Markdown
Follow the Mode.MARKDOWN description:
import { markdown as Terms1_MARKDOWN } from '@/assets/terms/terms1.md';

<textarea class="terms" cols="60" rows="40">{{ Terms1_MARKDOWN }}</textarea>

HTML from Markdown
For generating HTML from Markdown, follow the instructions of Mode.HTML:
import { html as Terms1_HTML } from '@/assets/terms/terms1.md';

<div v-html="Terms1_HTML" />

Vue Component
When using Vue, instead of HTML, you can also import Vue components. Follow the Mode.VUE description:
import { VueComponent } from '@/assets/terms/terms1.md';

<VueComponent />


When rendering the md file in the existing code, the path to the file was displayed on the screen instead of the desired text. However, when I changed the code as you suggested, nothing was displayed.

I couldn't quickly create a reproduction, you might need to use <pre>{{ terms1.markdown }}</pre> tags.

I tried everything but it all failed
Perhaps the method of importing from vite.config and defining it in plugins is wrong.

I've tested it, found the source of the error; it differs from what the documentation suggests. Added "Setup" part. Without modes and With modes.

Also, the plugin doesn't inject a default export into Markdown files, so only { markdown, html, VueComponent } work; you can't import them together in a shared object.

Sandbox Example

I just did it the way you said
It works the way I want it to.
thank you so much
